# Html couldn't find script

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying following code to show html page from webApi:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ManageAccount/{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ManageAccount(string id)
    {
        if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {

            var path = "C:/Users/user/Project/" + id + ".html";
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.Content = new StringContent(File.ReadAllText(path));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
            return response;

        }
        var path2 = "C:/Users/user/Project/Login.html";
        var response2 = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response2.Content = new StringContent(File.ReadAllText(path2));
        response2.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
        return response2;
       // return Redirect("Login.html");
    }
```

I set ContentType to be text/html to read html page, but this page has scripts, now all scripts read as text/html !

Please any suggestions?

How can I fix this ?

**Update:**

I got that if scripts loaded in server it work !

I don't know if there is a way to load my scripts on server and I don't know if this good idea !

Excuse me I'm new in this field :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `File.ReadAllText` is merely a method of reading text from a file
- `StringContent` is merely the structure that stores the text to add to the response body.

Both components do not include the server-side script compiler.

I think this is an MVC architecture problem! You probably know ASP.NET MVC provides two typical controller types: `Http.ApiController` and `Mvc.Controller`.

Simple to understand, `ApiController` is often used to handle data only, it is not equipped with the features used to handle Razor C #. Please using `Mvc.Controller` for do this.

Comment: Well, today i found some magic for your problem. You check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.viewengineresult

Answer (score 0):

Methods in the Web API 2 controllers may return different types.

- void(just returns the HTTP status code 204 to the client)
- HttpResponseMessage(Web API converts the return value to an HTTP response text)
- IHttpActionResult(the implementation of this interface allows you to create objects that implement different scenarios when processing the request)

If necessary, we can create our own class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using SomeApp.Models;

public class HtmlResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private User model;

    public HtmlResult(User model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string user = "<html><head><meta charset=utf-8 /></head></body>" +
            "<h2>" + user.Name + "</h2><h3>" + user.Login + "</h3><h3>"
            + user.Bday+ "</h3>" + "</body></html>";

        var tmp = new HttpResponseMessage();
        tmp.Content = new StringContent(user);
        tmp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");

        return Task.FromResult(tmp);
    }
}
```

Let's try to use:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int id)
{
    User user = _db.User.Find(id);
    return new HtmlResult(user);
}
```